# GoogleApiClient is not configured to use the API required for this call

Tags: android, google-places-api

I'm trying to get latitude and longitude of a place using Google Places API.

I'm following this example: [Google Directions Android](https://github.com/jd-alexander/Google-Directions-Android)

I configure the client like that:

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
            .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
```

But then here:

```
PendingResult<PlaceBuffer> placeResult = Places.GeoDataApi
                    .getPlaceById(mGoogleApiClient, placeId);
```

I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: GoogleApiClient is not configured to use the API required for this call.
```

How can I solve it?

I have the APIs activated on Google API console and I think I'm configuring it right, like the example.

Comment: did you add the proper configuration in the manifest file? https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/start

Comment: @MatiasElorriaga yes, I'm using the same API key that for Google Maps, and maps are working correctly.

Comment: are you calling `mGoogleApiClient.connect();`

Comment: yes, i'm doing it

Comment: mmm I would try calling only one api (in your case just .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)) and if that works, use two separate googleApiClients, one for LocationServices and one for Places. (I'm just guessing)

Comment: That worked! Thanks @MatiasElorriaga

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, after discussing it with @Daniel, the solution is to use two differents `GoogleApiClient` instances: one for LocationServices API and another for Places API.

Answer (score 0):

Just create two instance of GoogleApiClient as below and use accordingly:

```
 GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient1,mGoogleApiClient2;

        mGoogleApiClient1 = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
        .addApi(LocationServices.API)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .build();

        mGoogleApiClient2 = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .build();
```